# Getting an 'unexpected keyword argument' when deploying the python code using py-solcx for smart contracts

Tags: python, ethereum, solidity, web3py

I'm new to Solidity and Smart contracts stuff.

The code is taken from the repository provided by [PatrickAlphaC](https://github.com/PatrickAlphaC) under [here](https://github.com/PatrickAlphaC/web3_py_simple_storage/blob/main/deploy.py)

This is the code snippet I'm currently using.

```
from solcx import compile_standard, install_solc

install_solc("0.6.0")
with open("./SimpleStorage.sol", "r") as file:
    simple_storage_file = file.read()

compiled_sol = compile_standard(
    {
        "language": "Solidity",
        "sources": {"SimpleStorage.sol": {"content": simple_storage_file}},
        "settings": {
            "outputSelection": {
                "*": {
                    "*": ["abi", "metadata", "evm.bytecode", "evm.bytecode.sourceMap"]
                }
            }
        },
    },
    solc_version="0.6.0",
)
```

I've tried different solcx versions and it still throws some error.

this is the error that I'm getting

```
PS C:\Users\hp\web3_py_simple_storage> python -u "c:\Users\hp\web3_py_simple_storage\deploy.py"
solc, the solidity compiler commandline interface
Version: 0.6.0+commit.26b70077.Windows.msvc
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\hp\web3_py_simple_storage\deploy.py", line 7, in <module>
    compiled_sol = compile_standard(
                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\hp\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\solcx\main.py", line 158, in compile_standard
    stdoutdata, stderrdata, command, proc = solc_wrapper(
                                            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\hp\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\solcx\utils\string.py", line 85, in 
inner
    return force_obj_to_text(fn(*args, **kwargs))
                             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
TypeError: solc_wrapper() got an unexpected keyword argument 'solc_version'
PS C:\Users\hp\web3_py_simple_storage>
```

Can somebody help? The Maintainer on the [GitHub page](https://github.com/PatrickAlphaC/web3_py_simple_storage/issues?q=is%3Aissue+is%3Aclosed) isn't responding.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
from solcx import compile_standard, install_solc

install_solc("0.6.0")
with open("./SimpleStorage.sol", "r") as file:
    simple_storage_file = file.read()

compiled_sol = compile_standard(
    {
        "language": "Solidity",
        "sources": {"SimpleStorage.sol": {"content": simple_storage_file}},
        "settings": {
            "outputSelection": {
                "*": {
                    "*": ["abi", "metadata", "evm.bytecode", "evm.bytecode.sourceMap"]
                }
            }
        },
    },
    version="0.6.0",
)
```

**Walkthrough of my answer:**

I am not familiar with solc package, however it seems that you are installing an old version of it `install_solc("0.6.0")`. So I went to the git of solcx and change the tag to the right version and found the function solc_wrapper [link](https://github.com/ApeWorX/py-solc-x/blob/v0.6.0/solcx/wrapper.py). I couldn't find any argument as `solc_version` but it seems that `version` is what the author meant.